# MAMP: Apache Server is shut down automatically in Windows 10

Tags: apache, windows-10, mamp

**OS**:  *Windows 10*
**MAMP**: *4.1.1*

After installation, every time I run the program, Apache light goes green for a second and then turns off automatically. `MySQL` runs fine though.

The log file located at `C:\MAMP\logs\apache_error.log` contains these lines.

```
[Fri Jan 17 18:03:42 2020] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]  
[Fri Jan 17 18:03:43 2020] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?  
[Fri Jan 17 18:03:43 2020] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...  
[Fri Jan 17 18:03:43 2020] [notice] Digest: done
```

I find a lot of people online encountered the same situation as mine. But I cannot find out the solution. So I come here to find the potential solution.

P.S. I don't have the common Port `80` confliction problem. So I'm sure my problem is not related to it.

Comment: I found a way to circumvent this problem, although I don't understand why this works.

I found this approach on Super User
[link](https://superuser.com/questions/1485892/apache-not-starting-in-mamp-but-mysql-working-in-windows-10).

Change the MAMP settings by: **MAMP -> Preferences -> PHP**. Change Standard Version `7.3.7` to `7.2.14`. Click Okay and start the servers. Then everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to C:\MAMP\conf\apache\extra.

Edit the httpd-ssl.conf and comment the following line:

```
...
SSLSessionCache        shmcb:/some/example/path/ssl_scache(512000)
...
```

To:

```
...
# SSLSessionCache        shmcb:/some/example/path/ssl_scache(512000)
...
```

Also, check out https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/SSLSessionCache for more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry, but I didn't try it. Because I found an approach to circumvent it by changing the PHP version. Please refer to my own comment following my question.